# Web Service Test Cases

Tags: testing, testcase

I have recently move to web service testing. I need sample test cases for reference. Can any one please provide me the sample test cases written in excel for GET method, POST and PUT method.

Please tell me how to write test cases for testing search functionality through web services (GET method).

Thanks,
Sangeetha

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn how to use testing tools such as SOAPUI, Postman, Wizdler etc. 
Checkout these tutorials on getting start with some of them:

- https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/launching_postman/sending_the_first_request
- https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/getting-started.html
- https://www.guru99.com/webservice-testing-beginner-guide.html
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827113/Introduction-to-web-services-testing-and-soapUI